# Why does formatting guide use foo.com instead of example.com?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, formatting

I just noticed that the "How to Format" window that pops up when you're entering a question (and that is to the right of the text area into which I'm  typing this now) gives the hint:

> to make links
>
> <http://foo.com>
>   [foo](http://foo.com)
>   <a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>

Why does this example use the **foo.com** domain (which is registered to a company called Digimedia) and not the **[example.com](http://example.com/)** domain, which was created specifically for this sort of situation?

More info about example.com on the IANA website: https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved

Comment: [foo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) is a common example word used for any code. I can see why it would be used. And it is not like it is linked to the site.

Comment: @SurajRao The links in the How to Format window are not problematic as such; but the example they're setting is. At this moment there are 4767 questions and answers containing "foo.com"; many of these will have real links.

Comment: I thought the editor forces you to replace such links with the `example.com` links anyway.

Comment: @Nisarg Shah: You must have been imagining things. The editor has never done that.

Comment: @BoltClock I think I remember seeing a warning like this while editing one of the questions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQXKQ.png It could be on some other SE site though.

Comment: @BoltClock It does that for a lot of sites, for example `xyz.com`, `abc.com`, `mysite.com`, etc: https://i.stack.imgur.com/voSV0.png. But it doesn't block `foo.com`. Maybe `foo.com` should be added to the blacklist.

Comment: @Donald Duck: Ah, OK. What a strange omission, then...

Comment: What about "bar.com"?  Where does it end?

Comment: @MartinJames did not expect to see [that](https://bar.com/)

Comment: This was likely done because the sidebar used to be too small and using "example.com" caused the last example to [break onto a new line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ogq4.png). But that's not a problem anymore.

Comment: @animuson That deserves to be an answer, imo.

Comment: [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761): Analogous to Special-Use IPv4 Addresses [RFC5735], the Domain Name System (DNS) [RFC1034][RFC1035] has its own concept of reserved names, such as "example.com.", "example.net.", and "example.org.", or any name falling under the top-level pseudo-domain "invalid."

Comment: Does it matter? It won't affect the people at foo.com in any way. You would use example.com when people might actually try to access that site, for example in code samples, so as not to bother anyone.

Comment: @dan-gph Yes, it matters. `foo.com` might one day resolve to a malware website, for example.

Comment: @MartinJames With foobar.com

Comment: @Stijn Good prediction!

Comment: @animuson This issue seems to have been fixed. Can I add the status-completed tag myself or is that a job for moderators or staff?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, that's definitely a bad design because `foo.com` is now an advert site, live!!!

You should totally drop that and use <s>jQuery</s> `example.com` because it's the domain that ICANN reserved for example/demonstration purposes.

> [image: sss]

Note: I do NOT own the website nor do I have anything to do with it. I just came across this MSO question and decided to give it a try to find out what it was.